# Why is this MutexGuard not dropped?

Tags: rust, lifetime

In [Chapter 20 of The Rust Book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch20-02-multithreaded.html), an example implementation of a thread pool is built. Jobs are passed to workers via a single-producer multiple-consumer channel: each worker has an `Arc<Mutex<Receiver>>` to pick jobs off the queue.

The first example of the worker thread body looks like this:

```rust
loop {
    let job = receiver.lock().unwrap().recv().unwrap();

    println!("Worker {} got a job; executing.", id);

    job();
}
```

When I saw this my first thought was "but the mutex is held while `job` is run" (i.e. I did not expect the mutex to be released until the return value of `lock` went out of scope at the end of the loop).

However the book then provides a second example:

```rust
while let Ok(job) = receiver.lock().unwrap().recv() {
    println!("Worker {} got a job; executing.", id);

    job();
}
```

The book says that *this* example exhibits the problem I described, i.e. "the lock remains held for the duration of the call to `job()`". It goes on to say that the former example escapes the issue because "the `MutexGuard` returned from the `lock` method is dropped as soon as the `let job` statement ends".

That last part makes it sound as if, because the `MutexGuard` is never actually assigned to a variable, its lifetime ends as soon as the expression is finished evaluating. That would make sense. But isn't that also true of the second example? Why does being in a `while` expression change the lifetime of the `MutexGuard` value?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Michael's answer is basically correct. More details can be found in [Rust's reference regarding Place Expressions, Value Expressions and Temporary Lifetimes](https://doc.rust-lang.org/beta/reference/expressions.html#temporary-lifetimes):

In the first example (`let job = ...`), the `MutexGuard` is a temporary. The temporary lifetime ends at the end of the statement. Therefore the `MutexGuard` is dropped after the `let job = ...` statement.

In the second example `while let ...`, the `MutexGuard` is part of the [scrutinee](https://doc.rust-lang.org/beta/reference/glossary.html#scrutinee) of the `while`-expression. This makes the `MutexGuard` part of a value-expression in a place-expression context. Since promotion to a `'static` can't occur, the lifetime of the entire `scrutinee` is the enclosing block, not the enclosing statement. That is, the `MutexGuard` is held for the whole `while let`-block.

Comment: That first link contains a counter-example to my simplified view of what was happening. "`while foo(&temp()) {bar();}`. The temporary containing the return value from the call to temp() is created in the loop conditional expression. Hence it will be freed at the end of the loop conditional expression; in this example before the call to bar if the loop body is executed.". My explanation would have had `&temp()` living until the end of the loop

Comment: The `foo(&temp())` expression is not bound, it's a `while x`, not `while let x = y`. The `&temp()` can therefor be freed at the end of the loop conditional expression. It's the binding via `while let x = y` which requires extending the temporary lifetime of `y`to the whole block, so one can actually use `x`.

Comment: It's not obvious to me why Rust works this way. Is this a feature people use or just a happenstance?

Comment: @Brendan This is definitely a feature people use (whether it was intended this way though is debatable). Say you're writing a macro that accepts an expression that you need to use the result of multiple times, it may cause an error if you just assign the result of it to a variable since it may yield a value with a reference to a temporary. You can use a dummy `match $expr { value => ... }` so that `value` can be used multiple times within the arm since the life of the original expression is extended.

Answer (score 7):

The temporaries are cleaned up at the end of the statement, not the end of the expression.

In this case the whole while block is the statement, not just the expression inside the `let` pattern matching.

Comment: This way of thinking about the behaviour is overly simplified, the answer by user2722968 is more complete (but requires a deeper understanding of how all rusts syntax fits together.)